# Scala REPL: Where to find documentation on particular command?

Tags: scala

In scala REPL, one can show available commands by `:help`

```
scala> :help
All commands can be abbreviated, e.g., :he instead of :help.
...
:help [command]          print this summary or command-specific help
...
...
:reset [options]         reset the repl to its initial state, forgetting all session entries
...
```

For instance, where can I find the `[options]` of `:reset` command?
I tried `:help reset` which gives

> reset the repl to its initial state, forgetting all session entries

which is same as those shown in `:help`, not so helpful

I'm using Scala version 2.11.7

Comment: Did you check http://docs.scala-lang.org/scala/2.11#repl ?

Comment: @SudhirSingh As the page says, its an overview

Answer (score 1):

Though it's not a full documentation, this conversation points out how to use `reset`/`replay` commands:

https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/3986